# How to show keek videos in your website using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to show my keek video in my code using iframe. but did not get any code by google that let me know how can I integrate keek videos with site.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The button in the lower right corner that looks like a play button, right of the facebook icon, shows the embed code.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I just told you how to do that, why are you downvoting me?

Comment: ilia I did not down vote you and thanks for your reply I got my code. :)

Comment: ilia Can you please let me know about twitter video also ?

Comment: Ok. Not sure about twitter video, I don't think you are able to embed that

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<iframe width="480" height="390" src="https://classic.keek.com/embed/22Preab" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and you can find embed code from here:

[image]

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cxw80tux/

Comment: PHP Worm, Can you please let me know about twitter video also?